# Retrieving gmails through the browser

Tags: python, sockets, gmail, imaplib

I want to retrieve all the mails from my gmail adress in order to compute some satistics.
Problem is I need to run this at work and the connection to the imap google server is blocked and there is not much I can do about it.

As I can access my mails through the browser without any problem I was wondering if it were possible to retrieve it through this medium instead of using imaplib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmail has a REST api you could try:
[Quickstart: Run a Gmail App in Python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python)